# How to print an string array generated in processing to Arduino

Tags: string, arduino, processing

I'm trying to send a string generated in processing to Arduino so that it can be printed on an LCD screen. Nothing appears on the LCD using this method. I Have tried various methods and from my research the method I'm trying is this :

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

char inData[9]; // Allocate some space for the string
char inChar=-1; // Where to store the character read
byte index = 0; // Index into array; where to store the character

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);


void setup() {
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

 char Comp(char* This) {
while (Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
                               // there you know there is data
{
    if(index < 8) // One less than the size of the array
    {
        inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
        inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
        index++; // Increment where to write next
        inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
    }
}

if (strcmp(inData,This)  == 0) {
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        inData[i]=0;
    }
    index=0;
    return(0);
}
else {
    return(1);
}
}

void loop() 
{
if(Serial.available() > 0){
lcd.print(inData[index]);
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a data sheet for the lcd screen?

Comment: Its the liquid crystal display. https://www.engineersgarage.com/electronic-components/16x2-lcd-module-datasheet

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my anwser, but it might be because indata is being terminated before its even printed. Although i feel uneasy with my answser but hopefully it helped.

the termination:

```
    inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
```